# Adding http-header in Tomcat using vhost

Tags: tomcat, http-headers, vhosts

i'm running a web application on a Windows Server 2012 using Tomcat 8.5.

My current config is i have a .xml file in *conf/Catalina/localhost* pointing to the webapp.

I'm using ssl.

Everything is working fine (If i open the domain the webapp opens as planed)

What i need now is i need to configure a second domain pointing to the same webapp.

The difference should be domain1 don't set a http-header domain2 set a http-header.

Since i don't know much about Webservers/Tomcat: How can i add this to my Tomcat?

---

Hi, i installed an Apache and try to configure it. But there seems to be something wrong. I activated mod_proxy:

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

I configured a VirtualHost on port 443 in my httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@root.de
    ServerName internal.server.loc
    ServerAlias internal.server.loc
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass           /   http://localhost:8080/ Keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse    /   http://localhost:8080/
    Timeout 2400
    ProxyTimeout 2400
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCompression off
    SSLCertificateFile "D:\Apache24\conf\internal.server.loc.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:\Apache24\conf\internal.server.loc.key"
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://internal.server.loc/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

In my Tomcat i defined a connector on port 8080

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
port="8080" proxyName="internal.server.loc" proxyPort="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000" />
```

But if i start the apache and the tomcat, i always get an internal Server Error.

__

The application now opens, but the SSl isnt secure. Only a part of my application loads until i allow unsecure scripts.

i changed the config to my current setup.

The Only error i get in apache is:

[Mon Mar 19 14:47:21.195215 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 704:tid 440] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

In my Tomcat i cant find an error.

Comment: One solution is to use Apache as a gateway proxy. It's probably also possible to configure this directly in Tomcat, but probably a bit harder.

Comment: that would be totally fine for me. What do i have to install to use a gateway proxy?

Comment: [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) can be used as a gateway proxy. Bind the tomcat port to localhost and use a [ProxyPass directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) in Apache. You can then manipulate headers with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html).

Comment: I edited some more informations in my question, if you could help me out again i would be very thankful

Comment: The internal server error comes from your application. Check the log files and add any relevant information in your question.